# How to set off screen gesture Programmatically?

Tags: android, gesture

I want to set OnGesturePerformedListeners.

I created one service and one broadcast receiver when to set OnGesturePerformedListener.

How to detect when I draw round gesture in off screen?

Answer (score 0):

Well, to draw something on turned off screen, you should have access to device firmware. After screen is turned off, normally you couldn't receive anything from `InputManager`